# how to make static plane html page without db connection in prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

how to make static plane html page without db connection in prestashop 1.6
Because I don't want db errors when there is high traffic, So I want to create a static page (which I already created -plane html page),But I need to display this in the home page index page . how to do this without any db connection

Comment: have you tried something or you just want us to write the whole code for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this :

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($url=="/"){
 include("home.php"); exit;
 header("Location:http://981.11.115.222/home_staticpage.php"); exit;
 }
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

Where http://981.11.115.222/home_staticpage.php is my static page